# Javascript erasing old elements using html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have sliders which gives user chance to choose time range . Based on this time range some messages printed in the screen with some style. I am kinda generating style for those messages between following tags.

```
                <section> .... </section>
```

When I change my slider values which determines the range of the new messages, the new ones come behind old messages.  I just want the all messages from the new range not old one .
You can see jsFiddle of my code also [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p8cbw/)

```
$(function() {
        $( "#slider-5" ).slider({
           range:true,
           min: parseInt(ctime[0]),
           max: parseInt(ctime[ctime.length-1]),
           values: [ parseInt(ctime[4]),parseInt(ctime[len])],

           change: function( event, ui ) {
              $( "#slidevalue" )
                 .val( formatDateTime(ui.values[ 0 ]) + " - " + formatDateTime(ui.values[ 1 ]) );

                 new_var=ui.values[0];

                 var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
                 var section = document.createElement('section');
                 section.id = 'cd-timeline';
                 section.className = 'cd-container';
                 body.appendChild(section);

                 for (var x=0;parseInt(ctime[x])<ui.values[0];x++);

                 for (var x = 0;parseInt(ctime[x])<=ui.values[1]; x++) {
                     var datum = new Date(parseInt(ctime[x]));
                     var outerDiv = document.createElement('div');
                     outerDiv.className = 'cd-timeline-block';
                     section.appendChild(outerDiv);

                     var div = document.createElement('div');
                     div.className = 'cd-timeline-img cd-location';
                     outerDiv.appendChild(div);

                     var img = document.createElement('img');
                     img.src = 'img/cd-icon-location.svg';
                     img.setAttribute('alt', 'Location');
                     div.appendChild(img);

                     var div = document.createElement('div');
                     div.className = 'cd-timeline-content';
                     outerDiv.appendChild(div);

                     var h2 = document.createElement('h2');
                     div.appendChild(h2);
                     h2_text = document.createTextNode('foo');
                     h2.appendChild(h2_text);

                     var p = document.createElement('p');
                     div.appendChild(p);
                     p_text = document.createTextNode(<?php echo json_encode($content);                                           ?>[x]);
                     p.appendChild(p_text);

                     var span = document.createElement('span');
                     span.className = 'cd-date';
                     div.appendChild(span);
                     span_text = document.createTextNode(formatDateTime(datum));
                     span.appendChild(span_text);
                 }
           }
       });
     });
```

Comment: Why are you doing stuff like `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]` if you're using jQuery?

Comment: Please make a JSFiddle (jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Because i tried to it without it but it  did  not respond

Comment: Why are you directly appending it to `body`? doesn't it have any other content? If not use `body.innerHTML`, if you have other content, put the content you want to clear in a `<div>` and clear the div every time….

Comment: Or, why are you creating new sections every time..? looks like you just want to have a single section?

Comment: I want to have just 1 section. To tell the truth I am too damn new in this stuffs.

Comment: @MIRMIX then hope the answer helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>If i understood correctly,</strike> (*it appears to be correct from comments*) You don't need to append new `<section>` every time the slider is changed (*If you're doing this note that you can't use the same `id` for multiple elements*).

Have the `<section>` in `HTML`, like

```
<section id="cd-timeline" class="cd-container"></section>
```

then you can replace it's content using `$('#cd-timeline').html();` as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-5" ).slider({
       range:true,
       min: parseInt(ctime[0]),
       max: parseInt(ctime[ctime.length-1]),
       values: [ parseInt(ctime[4]),parseInt(ctime[len])],

       change: function( event, ui ) {
          $( "#slidevalue" )
             .val( formatDateTime(ui.values[ 0 ]) + " - " + formatDateTime(ui.values[ 1 ]) );

             new_var=ui.values[0];

             for (var x=0;parseInt(ctime[x])<ui.values[0];x++);

             for (var x = 0;parseInt(ctime[x])<=ui.values[1]; x++) {
                 var datum = new Date(parseInt(ctime[x]));
                 var outerDiv = document.createElement('div');
                 outerDiv.className = 'cd-timeline-block';
                 $('#cd-timeline').html(outerDiv); // replace the content of existing section

                 var div = document.createElement('div');
                 div.className = 'cd-timeline-img cd-location';
                 outerDiv.appendChild(div);

                 var img = document.createElement('img');
                 img.src = 'img/cd-icon-location.svg';
                 img.setAttribute('alt', 'Location');
                 div.appendChild(img);

                 var div = document.createElement('div');
                 div.className = 'cd-timeline-content';
                 outerDiv.appendChild(div);

                 var h2 = document.createElement('h2');
                 div.appendChild(h2);
                 h2_text = document.createTextNode('foo');
                 h2.appendChild(h2_text);

                 var p = document.createElement('p');
                 div.appendChild(p);
                 p_text = document.createTextNode(<?php echo json_encode($content);                                           ?>[x]);
                 p.appendChild(p_text);

                 var span = document.createElement('span');
                 span.className = 'cd-date';
                 div.appendChild(span);
                 span_text = document.createTextNode(formatDateTime(datum));
                 span.appendChild(span_text);
             }
       }
   });
 });
```

Comment: It just print the last message

Comment: @MIRMIX that is what you asked for - *"My question is how i can remove my old messages"*

Comment: I mean that " the new ones come behind old messages. My question is how i can remove my old messages.". I just want the all messages from the new range not old one

Comment: @MIRMIX if whatever you're doing inside the loops is correct then it'll work. My answer shows how to replace content inside an element. Without all the code to reproduce, or a demo, we don't know what else you're talking about. for example we've no idea what's `ctime[0]`... Try updating the question to be more clear, if possible including a minimal demo.

Answer (score 0):

Before appending child elements to the 'section' you can say

```
  $('section').children().remove();
```

to get rid of everything within the 'section'

This will take everything inside of your section and remove it. Be careful though. If you have other elements within your section already, those will be removed too. If you want to avoid that. Put your content that will be added and the stuff to be removed inside of an element that is seperate from the other content.

Like this

```
<section>
    <div>
        //all your other content
    </div>

    <div id='sliderContent'>
        //all your slider content
     </div>
</section>
```

Then in your jquery use instead

```
$('section #sliderContent').children().remove();
```

This will make it so you do not have to append a section to the dom anymore

Comment: @tlindell `html()` returns a string, which has no property `remove`. Assuming you meant `$("section").remove` - this is a function which requires `()` in order to execute, so it should be `$("section").remove()`

Comment: The reason I originally did the .html().remove was because it looked like op just had a string inside of the section.  Is my answer still incorrect?

Comment: jQuery has `empty` method. `$collection.empty()`

Comment: I will have to look at that. I have seen it before but never used it. You like it better than remove?

Answer (score 0):

How to remove the section: `$("section").remove();`
How to remove its children: `$("section").children().remove();`